# How can I set the value of instance from another instance?

Tags: xslt-2.0, orbeon, xforms, xsltforms, xforms-betterform

I have an instance on the page. However, I want the content of this instance to have some content which is part of another instance.

```
<xf:instance id="subInstance">
    <data xmlns="">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$newType= 'false' ">
                ???
                <xsl:copy-of select="????"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- add a new type -->
                <type>
                    <name/>
                    <base/>
                </type>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </data>
</xf:instance>
```

What should be in place of the question marks so that I can get the type from another instance ?

Or should I use `xf:setvalue` to set the instance on `xforms-model-construct-done` event? But isn't this the construction of the model itself ? I'm confused how to use values from another instance.

Can we use xf:insert somehow ?

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
          <xf:insert nodeset="instance('subInstance')" origin="instance('defaultType')/type"/>
      </xf:action>
```

This is not working. Is the event correct ? Since instance creation is part of model construction, I thought of using 'xforms-model-construct'. But still no luck !!

Comment: Is this with Orbeon Forms? Not all implementations support combining XSLT and XForms.

Comment: This is XSLTForms

Comment: Then I am not sure, but I believe that XSLT processing, it will happen before XForms processing. If you want to copy content from one instance to another you might want to use the XForms `<xf:insert>` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. The xf:insert does work. The event 'xforms-model-construct' was not being dispatched and that is why I felt it wasn't working. When I changed the event to 'xforms-model-construct-done', it worked.

```html
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
    <xf:insert nodeset="instance('subInstance')" origin="instance('defaultType')/type"/>
</xf:action>
```